# Indexing UUID on 80 million row table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

We're using Ruby on Rails migrations, with postgres, to add an index to a UUID type column on a table with 80 million rows.

We followed the `concurrently` pattern, and `disable_ddl_transaction!`. However, shortly after deploying, during the migration, we started noticing severe slowdowns and eventually the table stopped responding. We cancelled the migration mid-way through, the table finally recovered, but we still don't know what caused the table to stop responding.

We're using AWS RDS and we checked all the stats and it doesn't look like our CPU or I/O were maxed out.

My question is what other considerations could there be that could have caused us to slowdown/downtime during this migration?

Other tables were responding, the app was loading, but this one table was just stuck.

here's the migration:

```
class AddIndexToPublicId < ActiveRecord::Migration
  disable_ddl_transaction!

  def up
    change_column :table1, :public_id, :uuid, null: false
    change_column :table2, :public_id, :uuid, null: false
    change_column :table3, :public_id, :uuid, null: false
    add_index :table1, :public_id, unique: true, algorithm: :concurrently
    add_index :table2, :public_id, unique: true, algorithm: :concurrently
    add_index :table3, :public_id, unique: true, algorithm: :concurrently
  end

  def down
    remove_index :table1, :public_id
    remove_index :table2, :public_id
    remove_index :table3, :public_id
    change_column :table1, :public_id, :uuid, null: true
    change_column :table2, :public_id, :uuid, null: true
    change_column :table3, :public_id, :uuid, null: true
  end
end
```

the `change_column` part of the migration seemed to work fine but the indexing didn't finish so we're in a weird state right now where our schema.rb doesn't match our db.

Answer (score 2):

I think it slows because you are adding many concurrently indexes at a time. According to [Postgres document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY)

> When this option is used, PostgreSQL must perform two scans of the table, and in addition it must wait for all existing transactions that could potentially modify or use the index to terminate.

so when a concurrently index is added, **Postgres must perform two scans of table.**

Try to break down your migrations:

- One migration for `change_column`.
- One migration for each `add_index`.

And run only one at a time.

Comment: So we learned a bit more. We actually never got past the `null: false` part. We reran the migration and finally did get past that. Then, we went to finish the migration and adding an index to table1 caused more downtime/slowness. We looked at IO/CPU and nothing was spiking.